# Summing Rows Next to a Name in R

Tags: r

I'm working on a banking project where I'm trying to find a yearly sum of money spent, while the dataset has these listed as monthly transactions.

```
Month     Name                  Money Spent
  2      John Smith                   10
  3      John Smith                   25
  4      John Smith                   20
  2      Joe Nais                     10
  3      Joe Nais                     25
  4      Joe Nais                     20
```

Right now, this is the code I have:

```
OTData <- OTData %>%
mutate(
    OTData,
    Full Year = [CODE NEEDED TO SUM UP]
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's no question here.  What have you tried?  What error did you get?  Reference dplyr's group by and summarise functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Pawel said, there's no question here. I assume you want:

```
df <- data.frame(Month = c(2,3,4,2,3,4),
                 Name = c("John Smith", "John Smith", "John Smith",
                          "Joe Nais", "Joe Nais", "Joe Nais"),
                 Money_Spent = c(10,25,20,10,25,20))
df %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarize(Full_year = sum(Money_Spent))

  Name       Full_year
  <fct>          <dbl>
1 Joe Nais          55
2 John Smith        55
```

**NOTE**: You're going to run into trouble if you include spaces in your variable names. You really should replace them with `.`, `_`, or `camelCase` as in the above example.

Comment: Assuming I had many names and many sums, how would that change the "Name = c" and Money_Spent=c" part of the code?

Comment: It is column names  (like `'Money Spent'` and `'Full Year'` in your example) that shouldn't have spaces. The values of `Name` are just strings and can have spaces if you want. I'm not sure if I'm understanding your comment correctly.